# PHP Structure - Multiple IF GET statements on one page, or multiple pages?

Tags: php, html, oop

I've been developing in PHP for a few years, but one thing I constantly question is whether I should structure my pages like so:

```
            if(getValue('action') == "jobsFilter" && getValue('jobType') == "open")
            {
                $job->FetchJobs($jobStatus = 1);
                foreach($job->result AS $pulledJob)
                {
                ?>
                <div class = "openJob panelJob col-xs-12">
                    <h2><?php echo $pulledJob['jobTitle'] ?></h2>
                    <a href = "?action=viewJob&jobId=<?php echo $pulledJob['Id'] ?>" class = "viewJobBtn ">View Job</a>
                </div>
                <?php
                }       
            }else if(getValue('action') == "jobsFilter" && getValue('jobType') == "active")
            {
                $job->fetchAllJobsAppliedToUser($jobStatus = 1);
                foreach($job->result AS $pulledJob)
                {
                ?>
                <div class = "openJob panelJob col-xs-12">
                    <h2><?php echo $pulledJob['jobTitle'] ?></h2>
                    <a href = "?action=viewJob&jobId=<?php echo $pulledJob['Id'] ?>&jobStatus=1" class = "viewJobBtn ">View Details</a>
                </div>
                <?php
                } 
            }else if(getValue('action') == "viewJob" && isset($_GET['jobId']))
            {
                $job->FetchJobs($jobStatus = 1, $jobId = $_GET['jobId']);
                foreach($job->result AS $pulledJob)
                {
                ?>
                <div class = "viewJob panelJob col-xs-12">

                    <div class = "pulledJobInfo">
                        <h2><?php echo $pulledJob['jobTitle'] ?></h2>
                        <p><?php echo $pulledJob['JobDescription'] ?></p>
                    </div>

                    <form method = "post" action = "?action=acceptJob">
                        <input type = "submit" name = "acceptJobSubmitBtn" class = "acceptJobBtn fullWidthButton ctaButton" value = "Let me help" />
                        <input type = "hidden" name = "jobId" value = "<?php echo $pulledJob['Id'] ?>" />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <?php
                }                    
            }
```

Or whether I should have a separate page, called open-jobs.php for open jobs, closed-jobs.php for closed jobs, etc.

If someone could shed some light on the best solution, that'd be great!

Comment: It is primarily an opinion based question. However, you can ow start looking at the mvc framework to get better structure of your program

Comment: You use a single page for the "action" verb in your API. However then instead of using multiple "if" conditionals (or preferably a "switch" statement) you should implement a controller loading an object specialized in handling actions. That object offers methods for each type of action.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've never properly looked into MVC. At the moment, I'm just building a MVP for my startup, so sticking to what I know. In the future, however, I plan to look at more MVC driven languages, such as Ruby On Rails.

Comment: @Arkascha could you elaborate a bit more on how I'd implement something like that? I think I understand the logic, but I'm not quite sure what you mean by a controller loading an object. I've been out of OOP for a few months now, and even when I was deep in it, my career has pushed me a lot towards SQL development haha

Comment: You will find many examples for such controllers. What they basiclly do in typical php applications is: load some class definition based on php's autoloading function (which works string based). Then an object of that class is instantiated (here maybe class "Job"), inside that object a method is called (maybe called "filter" or "view").

Comment: @arkascha Awesome, thanks. I'll give it a look

Comment: Actually you probably want to slit your _combined_ action terms into separate terms for the object and the action, _unless_ the object is set implicitly for example by the API endpoint. So something like https://...../job/filter, or, after internal rewriting https://.....?object=job&action=filter.

Answer (score 1):

## Option A:

```
       if(getValue('action') == "jobsFilter" && getValue('jobType') == "open")
       {
           $job->FetchJobs($jobStatus = 1);
           $file="view1"
       }else if(getValue('action') == "jobsFilter" && getValue('jobType') == "active")
       {
           $job->fetchAllJobsAppliedToUser($jobStatus = 1);
           $file="view2"

       }else if(getValue('action') == "viewJob" && isset($_GET['jobId']))
       {
           $job->FetchJobs($jobStatus = 1, $jobId = $_GET['jobId']);
           $file="view3"                                
       }

       if($job != null){
         foreach($job->result AS $pulledJob)
         {
          include($file)
         }   
       }
```

## Option B:

```
       // Logic what to display
       switch(getValue('action')){
       
        case "jobsFilter":

          switch (getValue('jobType')){
            case "open":
              $job->FetchJobs($jobStatus = 1);
              $file="view1"
              break;
            case "active":
              $job->fetchAllJobsAppliedToUser($jobStatus = 1);
              $file="view2" 
              break;             
          }

        case "viewJob":
          $job->FetchJobs($jobStatus = 1, $jobId = $_GET['jobId']);
          $file="view3"  
          break;
       }

       // Execute the display
       if($job != null){
         foreach($job->result AS $pulledJob)
         {
          include($file)
         }   
       }
```